# Change how button looks when path changes

Tags: reactjs

main app which the switches occur looks like this

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar/>
          <div className="content">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <Home/>
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/create">
                <Create/>
              </Route>
            </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
```

My Navbar component currently looks like this

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"


const Navbar = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(window.location.pathname)
  }

  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <h1>Testing</h1>
      <div className="links">
          <Link to="/" onClick={handleClick}>Home</Link>
          <Link to="/create"
                style = {{
                  color: 'white',
                  backgroundColor: '#2d38d4',
                  borderRadius: '8px'
          }}>Finance</Link>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
   
export default Navbar;
```

I was going going to use `handleClick` to make it so the one clicked receives the styling however I realized that if I did do this, it wouldn't change the button appearances if someone just directly changed the url like this `localhost/ ->  localhost/app` and vise versa.

How are selections like this managed in React?

---

Inspired by the answer I marked correct here it is:

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom"


const Navbar = () => {
  const activeStyle = {
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: '#2d38d4',
    borderRadius: '8px'
  }

  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <h1>Testing</h1>
      <div className="links">
          <NavLink exact to="/"
                activeStyle = {activeStyle}>Home</NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/create"
                activeStyle = {activeStyle}>Finance</NavLink>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
   
export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the NavLink component rather than the Link component as the NavLink one will automatically add an active class to the link if you are on the same Route that the to is set to.

```js
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom"


const Navbar = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(window.location.pathname)
  }

  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <h1>Testing</h1>
      <div className="links">
          <NavLink to="/" onClick={handleClick}>Home</NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/create">Finance</NavLink>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
   
export default Navbar;
```

Then in your CSS (however you are doing it) you just need to style the active class.

The official docs also has some examples of how to give your own active class or style the link directly like you had originally.
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink